# Rails validation based on certain action like create/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How do I perform validation of a particular element based on a certain action(update/create) inside the validation class in rails?

I'm trying to do validation of date something like this

```
class SampleValidation < ApiValidation
  validate :date_format_validation

  def date_format_validation
    errors[:start_date] << :must_be_a_valid_date unless (DateTime.parse(visible_from) rescue false) # I want to perform this only on create not on update
    errors[:end_date] << :must_be_a_valid_date unless (DateTime.parse(visible_from) rescue false) # Want to perform this on both create and update
  end
end
```

I want to perform it only while creation & not during updation, how can I check "action" inside date_format_validation.

I want something like, using "action" in Controller I can get the particular action which is called. ie create/update

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: corrected it, wrote in a more meaning full way.

Answer (score 0):

usually you put validations in Model, and By default, validations are run on save (both create and update operations). If you need to do so, you
can limit a given validation to just one of those operations by passing the :on option either :create or :update.

```
class SampleValidation < ApiValidation
  validate :date_format_validation, on :create

  def date_format_validation
    errors[:visible_from] << :must_be_a_valid_date unless (DateTime.parse(visible_from) rescue false)
  end
end
```